# scripts not working inside dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery

If found some posts about jQuery .load(url) and the firing problem, but I don't find a solution or I am not really understand them - sorry for that.

So far, is this correct?:

- .load(url) content isn't really DOM loaded?
- it needs a callback to fire?

My Example:

I have a "main.php" with a list. I load the content for the list from an other php, its called "my_list.php".

The "my_list.php" has some jQuery scripts inside. For example, if I press a link a modal will open.

So, if I directly open "my_list.php" all scripts work fine. If I load the content from "my_list.php" inside the "main.php", the scripts inside the "my_list.php" will no longer firing at click aso.

I load the content like this way:

```
$( "#list" ).load( "my_list.php .list_wrapper" );
```

---

**I found a solution:**
You just have to add your required scripts/functions for the loaded content like this:

```
$( "#list" ).load( "my_list.php .list_wrapper", function() {
    $.getScript("js/my_scripts_for_the_list.js"); 
});
```

Comment: Please use a term other than scripts.  It's very ambiguous.  Do you really mean "none of the scripts within script elements in my_list.php seem to work", or "none of the jQuery handlers (such as $('.list_wrapper').click(...) that I set up on document ready seem to work"... your questions doesn't provide enough details to help you.  Try showing us all relevant code in a minimal viable code example.

Comment: @Sam Axe Ok, sorry ... I mean "all scripts inside the my_list.php" will no longer work, if they are loaded inside the new page.

Answer (score 0):

Like the jQuery [$('#elem').load('/some-page.php')](http://api.jquery.com/load/) documentation says:

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

This means that a **GET** request will be made on the **/some-page.php**. That script/page should return a valid HTML response. That HTML response will be injected inside the given jquery element. The element will contain the retrieved HTML.

*Nice to know*: any dynamic content created via JS/AJAX on the page requested via `.load()` won't execute. Only the content rendered server-side will be retrieved.

If by accessing **/my_list.php** in your browser returns a valid HTML, try using it like so:

```
$("#list").load("my_list.php");
```

Comment: Hi. So, isn´t there any simple way to execute it? I read something about a callbacks?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. Please let me know if this works. Also make sure that the element `#list` exists in the DOM.

Comment: The content will be displayed, like my script do, but all scripts from my_list.php also don't execute ;( ...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by scripts?

Comment: I found a solution, I have updated my post - thx for your support so far!

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript will get executed fine from my_list.php, just make sure  it doesn't have any html, head, body tags. Remove these tags and only use div or spans. Because in current scenario after calling load to my_list.php, your page will have multiple html, head or body tags, which won't be rendered properly by browsers. Just remove html, head and body tags, everything should work fine. I hope this helps. 
PS: don't mind my English.